# SQL syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 including SQL Server Data Tools. The T-SQL editor underlines errors correctly, but there is no syntax color highlighting. All the text is black. See for example

[image]

SQL code used to be colored in Visual Studio 2015. Syntax color highlight still works well for C# on Visual Studio 2017.

I tried at work (Enterprise edition on Windows 7) and at home (Community edition on Windows 10), same result.

Is there something particular to do in order to enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there's a bug with non-english languge packages. I changed it to english as stated in this [post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/12692/no-syntax-highlighting-for-sql.html)  and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

With my Enterprise 2017 Version, I just had to install the English package to make coloration works, but no need to set Visual Studio in English, it's working in French.

[image]